# PDF print dialog get blank page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pdf, printing

I am trying to print previously streamed PDF document on browser, using *window.print()*.

The document is loaded but when I tied to print with windows.print() (**ctrl+P**) I get blank page on preview

I tried to put on **iframe** and **embed** or changing style, size... but all time I get blank page. 
[image: Blank Print[1]]

```
getPDF(pdfID: string) {   
 var winparams = 'dependent=yes,locationbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,' > 


 var printWindow = window.open("", "", winparams);
 var htmlPop;
 this.rs.grps(reportId).subscribe(
   (response) => {
     this.pdfSrc = "data:application/pdf;base64," + response;
     debugger;
     setTimeout(() => {
       htmlPop = '<embed style="display:block !important" width=100% height=100%'
         + ' type="application/pdf"'
         + ' src="'
         + this.pdfSrc
         + '"></embed>';


       printWindow.document.write(htmlPop);
      //window.print(); 
     }, 1000);

   }
 );
 setTimeout(() => {
   printWindow.print();
   printWindow.close();

 }, 5000);   }
```